# Taking the average p value from a set of simulated p values

Tags: simulation, p-value, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have 149 locations that are lined up from east to west. I have the geographical distances between each location and the adjacent location going west. I want to test whether the locations are randomly distributed or not. Therefore, I take the furthest west location and the furthest east location, and generate 145 random locations within this space and find the distance between each consecutive location (again from east to west). I then test the actual distribution of distances against the randomly generated distribution of distances using Kolmogorov Smirnov to get a p value.

However, if I then decide to do 1000 simulations, does it make sense to just calculate the average (or median) p value of the 1000 KS tests and report this?

Comment: No, I can't think of a situation where it makes sense to average p-values.  How are you randomly generating distances?  Couldn't you use the distribution you are using to generate the random distances as the null hypothesis in the KS test?

Comment: I'm generating the distances by randomly sampling a number between 0 and the distance to the furthest location. Essentially, this distribution is my null hypothesis. It's just that I would have thought repeating it would make the comparison between the actual and random distribution more robust. I'm using `sample.int` in R. Why wouldn't it be sensible to average p-values?

Comment: You said "Essentially this distribution is my null hypothesis." Exactly. In each simulation you are drawing a random sample from a probability distribution.  The CDF of that probability distribution should be your null hypothesis in the KS test.

Comment: As for the question "why wouldn't it be sensible to average p-values?", the reason is that the average of p-values doesn't have any reasonable interpretation I can think of.

Comment: @caburke How can I get the CDF of `sample.int(1000)` and then apply `diff(CDF)` to get the distances? If you put this down as an answer, I can accept.

Comment: @caburke I meant `sample.int(1000,145). However, rather than doing it empirically via `sample.int`, would it make more sense to do: use `rexp`? Not sure how though.

Comment: I think, going back a step, we need to clarify your research question "whether the locations are randomly distributed or not".  Perhaps you actually mean "distributed in accordance with a uniform random distribution or not".  Is the uniform distribution actually the crucial aspect of your null hypothesis?

Comment: @PeterEllis I suppose that's the question: should the null hypothesis be a uniform random distribution or a random exponential distribution? My initial thought was that a random exponential distribution of the distances was the better null hypothesis. Essentially, I want to test that the locations are not bundled together.

Comment: If you take random exponentials as the differences and condition on the overall total, you get random uniform distribution. They're not different assumptions, the only difference is the conditioning.

Answer (score 3):

See [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ks.test.html) for the documentation of R's implementation of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. The important thing is that you can choose a wide variety of distributions as your null hypothesis in the KS test, like the exponential distribution as you mentioned in a comment.

For your original question, it does not make sense to average p-values because an average p-value has no useful interpretation for your needs (or for anything that I am aware of). What you are trying to do, test whether the distances between locations follow some distribution, is exactly what the KS test does.

As an example, suppose you believe distances between the 145 locations in your data set follow a $U(0,1000)$ distribution.  Then if your 145 distances are in a vector named $\tt{x}$ in R, run

```
ks.test(x, punif, min=0, max=1000)
```

For the hypothesis that the data follows an exponential distribution with mean 2, the code is

```
ks.test(x, pexp, rate=0.5)
```

Comment: For the null hypothesis of an exponential distribution, would it be make sense to use the mean of the actual distribution of distances? Similarly, for the uniform, would I use the theoretical max and min distance s (distance between last and first locations; and 0) or the max and min observed distances?

Comment: Also, if I want to generate the exponential distribution outside ks.test, how is that done? The `quantile` argument isn't very clear to me?

Comment: if you use estimated parameters in the ks.test(), the p-value becomes invalid, as you can check via a Monte Carlo experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can combine p values using fisher's method. It's not a straight average, it is described here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method 
and probably many other places. This is assuming that the p values are independent though.